# What does давать изюминку mean? Give a raisin?

Tags: словоупотребление, сленг

In this comment:

> Ваша фраза супер!: "Чуть ли не все два читателя исправили эти имена, порекомендовали варианты или другое склонение." Именно противопоставление определенного количества "два" и неопределенного "чуть ли не" -- и дает эту изюминку!

Comment: "As many as about all two readers" - lolphrase.

Comment: "Just about every two readers..." я сам автор :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context, **изюминка** (raisin) means that **thing/person/something** is **special/unique**.
In relation to people, it means that a person has a unique property.
For example, `в тебе нет никакой изюминки` = `you have nothing special` or `you are an ordinary person`.

In your case, use of certain words makes the phrase special, more beautiful, unusual.

Answer (score 6):

`иметь изюминку` (`having a raisin`) means same as `salting` in `The book is a little dull, and needs salting with some interesting examples` - "having one extremely interesting / standing out feature that makes the whole object much more interesting".

In your example, is said that peculiar use of numerals is what provides that `изюминку`, a.k.a. `salting`.